# "Absent" as a preposition

Tags: prepositions

I've recently seen some people use *absent* as if it were a preposition. One example, which I found in the Christianity forum of Stack Exchange, is as follows:

> A Sinful nature provides an irresistable [sic] compulsion to sin, but even **absent** that, one can still partake in sin.

I cannot find the prepositional use of *absent* in any dictionary. Is it a new usage?

Comment: [So](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/absent) [far](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/absent) [every](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/absent) [one](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/absent) [does](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22absent%22&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&client=firefox-a)! Where did you look?

Comment: I can find its noun and verb entries, but not its preposition entry.

Comment: Please look in any of the several dictionaries that Susan and Jasper linked to.

Comment: [M-W](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/absent), [AHD](http://education.yahoo.com/reference/dictionary/entry/absent), [Wiktionary](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/absent?rdfrom=Absent#Preposition), [Oxford Dictionaries](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/absent), [The Free Dictionary](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/absent), [Dictionary.com](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/absent?r=66) and [Etymonline](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=absent) all have an entry on *absent* as a preposition. As the last one points out, the usage is at least 70 years old.

Answer (score 8):

*[Absent](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/absent)* is indeed used as a preposition to mean *without*.

Comment: Can you list a dictionary that has it as a preposition?

Comment: Check the linked dictionary.