# What does absent fraud mean?

Tags: meaning, expressions, terminology, phrase-meaning

I came across the phrase ***absent fraud*** in [this article.](https://www.linkedin.com/today/post/article/20140422105938-5015451-career-curveballs-how-getting-fired-for-alcohol-changed-my-life?trk=tod-home-art-list-large_0)

I searched for its meaning on Google but didn't find anything.

What does *absent fraud* mean?

> I can’t help but empathize with an employee being fired and will ask multiple questions before any termination. Was there one bad act or a series? Did they have feedback and a chance to change? Was it performance or personality? **Absent fraud or transgression**, is there a different job in the organization the employee could succeed at? How do we tell them and what, if any, severance is offered? What help can we offer in finding another job more suited to their skills? How can we preserve their dignity?

Comment: You should highlight the paragraph in the article, don't just add a link.

Comment: 'Absent fraud' is a legal term. The question may be better asked on a relevant Q&A site, or SO.

Comment: In American legal documents (and now sometimes in general American English), *absent* is often used as a preposition meaning *in the absence of*. See [this question](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/149696/absent-as-a-preposition).

Comment: @Kris - You've misunderstood the expression in the context of this question.

Comment: c.f. a fraudulent card-absent transaction

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Absent is not just a adjective modifying *fraud* in this case.

If you look at the context, we see this sentence:

> Absent fraud or transgression, is there a different job in the organization the employee could succeed at?

Which can loosely be read as:

> When there is no fraud or transgression, can we find the employee another job in the organisation?

**Absent (a or b)** means *in the absence of a or b*.

What the writer is saying, is that looking for another position is only on option when there is *no* fraud or transgression.

Comment: didn't even come closer to think this. I thought it was some fraud that happened because you were absent, and if present could have thwarted. Or some fraud you commit absent-mindedly. What would that be called I wonder.

Comment: @AnubhavSaini: fraud because you are absent would deal with _absence_, so that might be _absence fraud_. And the second one would be absent-minded fraud :)

Answer (score 0):

It simply defines 'no intent' to defraud.  For example, [Secretary of the Commonwealth v. City Clerk of Lowell,[9] holding that, **absent fraud**, people may select and change their names freely.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robert_Braucher#Judicial_career)  It is a term often seen in the 'Terms and procedures' of contracts